# Do lambdas in Java create anonymous class during execution/runtime?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, anonymous-class, functional-interface

In Java SE8 specification it is written: "*Evaluation of a lambda expression produces an instance of a functional interface*".

So far, my understanding is - *lambda expression creates some anonymous class that implements a functional interface*

Can someone explain in details, what happens in runtime with the lamda expressions that we write?

Comment: There's a `LambdaFactory` which spews something more akin to a function pointer than an anonymous class. For the purposes of development however, you can (and should) think of them as similar; the function API exists to represent and be interchangeable with method signatures

Comment: Your title and body don't match. Lambdas don't create new classes _during evaluation_, but they can (don't always) cause them to be created, and _instances_ of those anonymous classes are created when the expression is used.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- this question cites the language specification exactly. In this language, a lambda expression is this `argument -> body` thing that evaluates to an instance of a functional interface, not to confuse with the execution of the lambda expression’s body.

Answer (score 1):

No, they don't.

The *exact* mechanism on how the runtime represents lambdas is intentionally left under-specified.

All you know is that you'll get a valid object that implements the necessary interfaces/behaviours. But beyond that very little is specified. The spec doesn't even tell you if two calls to that will produce the same object or not.

This vague specification is done so that the compiler and/or the runtime can make optimizations without running afoul of the spec.

The relation with anonymous classes is more a historical one: if you wanted to do what lambdas do without using lambdas, then anonymous classes are your next-best tool.

Comment: The first line is inaccurate: In many cases, they _do_ create anonymous classes (generally named things like `ContainingClass.containingMethod$lambda$1`).

Comment: I consider that an implementation detail and it's not specified by the spec. Additionally I believe that the object returned by the lambda will actually be of that type.

Comment: Sure, it's not specified, but there's an important difference between "it's not specified" and "it doesn't happen", which it certainly does; furthermore, where the lambda is captured into a reference, it _must_ be an instance of _some_ synthetic class.

Comment: Sure, it must be an isntance of a class, but "anonymous class" has a very specific meaning and it's not just "any synthetic class".

Comment: Thank you. I tried find it in a certain books, but didn't found the answer you gave)